# Running wordpress in localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost

When I run wordpress folder in my localhost, (localhost/wordpress) I am getting the error as

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
>   Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/index.php' (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: What permissions are on your wordpress folder ?? which wordpress version you are using ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Apache or are you using EasyPHP or xampp for this install? Most likely its a permissions issue (chmod 777 in linux on the folder OR read/write in windows for the htdocs or www folder)